# Ruby on Rails, How to determine if a request was made by a robot or search engine spider?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search-engine, web-crawler

I've Rails apps, that record an IP-address from every request to specific URL, but in my IP database i've found facebook blok IP like 66.220.15.* and Google IP (i suggest it come from bot). Is there any formula to determine an IP from request was made by a robot or search engine spider ? Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Robots are required (by common sense / courtesy more than any kind of law) to send along a User-Agent with their request. You can check for this using `request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]` and filter as you please.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, yes i make an array of robot user-agent like : AM_I_ROBOT = ["googlebot","twitterbot",
    "facebookexternalhit", "http://www.google.com/bot.html",
    "http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php",
    "tweetmemebot", "sitebot", "msnbot", "robot", "bot"]

Comment: Here's a list of user agents:
http://www.user-agents.org/ with an XML feed:
http://www.user-agents.org/allagents.xml

Comment: This gist fetches the name of all search engine bots and spammers from user-agents.org and throws them in an array: https://gist.github.com/1121578
It's a pretty long list.

Comment: @sjors that's great except that database is notably missing, e.g. facebook's fetcher.

Comment: Stumbled across this gem https://github.com/biola/Voight-Kampff. It looks like it handles checking the User Agent so you don't have take an exhaustive approach to listing the User Agents that correspond to bots. Seems like a good, quick solution.

Answer (score 31):

Since the well behaved bots at least typically include a reference URI in the UA string they send, something like:

```
request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].match(/\(.*https?:\/\/.*\)/)
```

is an easy way to see if the request is from a bot vs. a human user's agent. This seems to be more robust than trying to match against a comprehensive list.

Comment: +1 For this clever solution, however, bear in mind that Twitter don't follow this rule, use `request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].match(/Twitterbot\/1.0/)`instead.

Comment: While this is maybe a clever solution to catch most search engine bots, it is not maintainable and will most likely miss many bots

Answer (score 14):

I think you can use **browser** gem for check bots.

```
if browser.bot?
  # code here
end
```

[https://github.com/fnando/browser](https://github.com/fnando/browser#rails-integration)

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use [crawler_detect](https://github.com/loadkpi/crawler_detect) gem:

```
CrawlerDetect.is_crawler?("Bot user agent")
=> true

#or after adding Rack::Request extension
request.is_crawler?
=> true
```

It can be useful if you want to detect a large various of different bots (more than 1000).

Comment: this one users regexp of concatenated using `|` user agents, but `browser` uses `crawler_list.includes?(current)`. This one may be faster