# Creating a simple hit counter in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, counter, visitor-statistic, impressions

I've been trying to implement the [gem Impressionist](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist), but as the doc is confusing and the gem carries a bit of overhead for my simple use case I wonder how I could go about implementing this myself?

- I want to track impressions (requests) of a certain action in a controller.
- The impressions don't have to be registered by unique visitors.
- I need the counter to be unique to each record in the model (i.e. Shop 1: 34 hits, Shop 2: 77 hits etc).
- The counter should not include requests from bots on this list: http://www.user-agents.org/allagents.xml

What would be the minimal code required to accomplish the above?

**Update**

To clarify, if possible I **don't** want to use the gem Impressionist. I only used that as a prelude to describe what problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: do you want to use the impressionist gem, or want to implement the gem yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an attribute to your model.

If you are using the Impressionsit gem, you should [use the built-in migration generator](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist/blob/74847f2d042102d10f6ccc3dda3d26d87e5f17ea/lib/generators/active_record/templates/create_impressions_table.rb) to add the correct scheme to your database.

Otherwise, if you are not planing to use this gem, you will need to create a migration like the following:

```
MyMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :pluralized_model_eg_users, :integer, default: 0
  end
end
```

Then, on the actions you want to count, use the code :

```
unless request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].match(/\(.*https?:\/\/.*\)/)
  @model.update_attribute :impressions, @model + 1
end
```

It does not uses the list you gave even to avoid overhead. However, [most robots have an url in his user agent to identify then](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882264/ruby-on-rails-how-to-determine-if-a-request-was-made-by-a-robot-or-search-engin), so using this should be safe.

Using the list from this site would need you to add a caching to that list, which might add uneeded complexity in your code if it aims to be a simple feature.